# Problemas com ORDER BY na pesquisa MY SQL

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Bom dia galera, como vai?

Estou com um probleminha para obter uma busca mais "avançada" com o meu MYSQL, vocês podem me ajudar?

criei uma pesquisa da seguinte maneira

`SELECT idproduto, descricao, vconsumidor FROM produtos WHERE descricao LIKE '%$descricao%' OR marca LIKE '%$descricao%'"`

vamos lá aos primeiros problemas

veja o exemplo:
ao pesquisar NORTON ele aparece todas as marcas da pesquisa MARCA

porém se coloco 'PEGA PO NORTON' ou 'NORTON PEGA PO' ele não retorna nada, pois o PEGA PO esta na descrição e o NORTON na marca

até ai resolvi da seguinte forma

```
    $descricaoalterada = str_replace(' ', '||', $descricao);
    //pega a descrição e altera todos os espaços por ||


    $d=explode("||", $descricaoalterada );
    //faz um array, com uma coluna pra cada || do resultado de cima

    $texto = "";

    for ($i=0; $i < count($d); $i++){
        $texto = $texto."OR descricao LIKE '%".$d[$i]."%' ";
        //para cada coluna do array ele cria no $texto um novo OR descricao LIKE %%
        //exemplo OR descricao LIKE %PEGA% OR descricao LIKE %PO% OR descricao LIKE %NORTON%
    } 
    
    $sqlT = "SELECT idproduto, descricao, vconsumidor FROM produtos WHERE descricao LIKE '%$descricao%' 
    ".$texto."OR marca LIKE '%$descricao%'";
    //exemplo impresso: SELECT idproduto, descricao, vconsumidor FROM produtos WHERE descricao LIKE '%PEGA PO NORTON%' OR descricao LIKE %PEGA% OR descricao LIKE %PO% OR descricao LIKE %NORTON% OR marca LIKE '%PEGA PO NORTON%'
    $resultT=mysqli_query($conexao,$sqlT);
```

ai ficou legal, retornou TUDO que tem PEGA PO NORTON no resultado, porém ele aparece primeiro a descricão, um exemplo é TINTA 'PO'LISTER que vem antes na descrição
ESTÁ IMPRIMINDO ASSIM:
TINTA POLIESTER
PEGA PO NORTON

como eu poderia fazer para primeiro ele retornar primeiro a consulta? exemplo todos os PEGA PO NORTON, depois aparecer tudo que tem PO ou PEGA ou NORTON?
como neste exemplo:

PEGA PO NORTON

TINTA POLIESTER
NORTON LIXA
ETC

Caso tenham outras formas melhores para exibir este resultado ficaria muito grato!!
desde já agradeço pela cooperação!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `LIKE` não ajuda muito nisso, então uma solução seria:

- Fazer duas queries diferentes e usar `UNION` para juntar os resultados, e com uma coluna de "prioridade";
- Ordenar por essa prioridade.

Não consigo montar um exemplo funcional agora, mas como sua query está pronta deve ficar bem consistente o exemplo (vou usar a query final, basta adaptar no `PHP`):

```
SELECT 1 AS  prioridade, idproduto, descricao, vconsumidor 
  FROM produtos 
 WHERE descricao LIKE '%PEGA PO NORTON%'
UNION
SELECT 2 AS prioridade, idproduto, descricao, vconsumidor 
  FROM produtos 
 WHERE descricao LIKE %PEGA% OR descricao LIKE %PO% OR descricao LIKE %NORTON% OR marca LIKE '%PEGA PO NORTON%'
ORDER BY prioridade
```

Note que a primeira query tem prioridade 1 e a segunda prioridade 2, o que vai fazer os resultados trazerem primeiro os resuldados da primeira query por causa do `ORDER BY`. Se precisar mudar a ordem, basta mover os critérios para a primeira query, ou adicionar mais se for o caso.

Isso funciona mas pode ser preciso usar `(` ou um `SELECT * FROM (... AQUI VÃO AS QUERIES..) ORDER BY prioridade` caso não esteja ordenando corretamente

Comment: muito bem colocado esse 1 as prioridade e depois ordenar por ela, nem sabia que isso era possivel, agora está exatamente como eu planejava, muito obrigado!